# Is there some identity to simplify $\cos ^{-1} (\cos(a)\cos(b))$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there some identity to simplify $\cos ^{-1} (\cos(a)\cos(b))$? When I set $b=\frac \pi 4$, it seems to be a sinusoid as a function of $a$, but if $b=0$, it's just a bunch of straight lines.

Comment: what does $cos^{-1}$ mean. Is it $\arccos$ or $1/cos$?

Comment: $\arccos$, not $\frac{1}{\cos}$

Comment: Isn't it already simple enough?